# How to import from a dynamic array

Tags: c#, dynamic, import

My program has to place objects on a map, i have to get the informations about the objects from a text file but my problem is that there is no limit in objects so when i write my code i don't know if someone wants to place 1 or 10 or 5 objects. Every object has a separate line where you can give the parameters for example x,y coordinates on the map to place etc etc.
I figured out that i will ask the user to write in a line before the objects the number of objects he wants to add.Here is my example :

txt file:

200<----not important here

10000<----not important here

5<---number of objects

2,5/60-60<--object

4,5/70-70<--object

5,5/80-80<--object

1,1/30-30<--object

10,10/100-100<--object

10,1/5<----not important here

height,weight/x-y

And vs throws out of range exception. Hope u understood my english and my problem

```
        int numberofObjects = int.Parse(data[2]);

        Targets[] TargetsGet = new Target[numberofObjects];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i <= numberofObjects+3; i++)
        {

            targets[j] = new Target(int.Parse(data[i].Split(',')[0]), int.Parse(data[i].Split('/')[0].Split(',')[1]), new Coordinate(int.Parse(data[i].Split('/')[1].Split('-')[0]),int.Parse( data[i].Split('-')[1])));
            j++;
        }

        return TargetsGet;



    }
```

Comment: If the file format is well defined (i.e. records are X size or records are separated by line breaks) then you easily know how many records there are (read all the data and count them, then transform them). But even then, a `foreach` over the data read is the "most" C# way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your solution works.
If you don't want to ask the user to specify the number of objects, you can use a list instead of an array and use a separator at the end of the object list. For example:

```
      List<Targets> TargetsGet = new List<Target>();
        int j = 0;
        while(data[j]!="separator")
        {
            targets.Add(new Target(int.Parse(data[j].Split(',')[0]), int.Parse(data[j].Split('/')[0].Split(',')[1]), new Coordinate(int.Parse(data[j].Split('/')[1].Split('-')[0]),int.Parse( data[j].Split('-')[1])));
            j++;
        }

        return TargetsGet.ToArray();
    }
```

The file should be modified so the string "separator" will be after the object list:, for example: 
200<----not important here

10000<----not important here

2,5/60-60<--object

4,5/70-70<--object

5,5/80-80<--object

1,1/30-30<--object

10,10/100-100<--object

separator

10,1/5<----not important here

height,weight/x-y